# java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack error when connecting to a Mongo Db database

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to connect to a Mongo db database using mongo db java driver. I was able to make a connection to the target database yesterday, but I've been stuck with this exception for a whole day now. Able to make a connection to a mongo db server started in my local machine. So I assume this may have something to do with the proxy or network settings. But I'm not able to understand the root cause from this exception message. Can someone suggest any solution please?

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(connectionString);
mongoClient.getDatabase("qadb")
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
Location:
com/sun/jndi/dns/Resolver.([Ljava/lang/String;II)V @10: invokestatic
Reason:
Type uninitializedThis (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'java/lang/Object'
Current Frame:
bci: @10
flags: { flagThisUninit }
locals: { uninitializedThis, '[Ljava/lang/String;', integer, integer }
stack: { uninitializedThis, '[Ljava/lang/String;', 'java/lang/Integer', 'java/lang/Integer' }
Bytecode:
0000000: 2a2b 1cb8 0092 1db8 0092 b800 982a b700
0000010: 012a 1cb5 0002 2a1d b500 032a bb00 0459
0000020: 2b1c 1db7 0005 b500 06b1

```
at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.getResolver(DnsContext.java:573)
at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.c_getAttributes(DnsContext.java:434)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:235)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:141)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:129)
at java.naming/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:142)
at com.mongodb.internal.dns.DefaultDnsResolver.resolveAdditionalQueryParametersFromTxtRecords(DefaultDnsResolver.java:114)
at com.mongodb.ConnectionString.<init>(ConnectionString.java:388)
at com.mongodb.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:61)
```

Detailed error message

[image: 1]

Comment: I was just trying to resolve the issue using trial and error and this issue was resolved when I updated the project JDK version to 1.8 from 11. Still don't understand what was cause causing the issue in the first place.

Comment: Hi, I am getting the exact same error when calling to
java.naming/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:142).


I am using JDK 11.04.
Upgrading the JDK resolved it?
Do you know what is the root cause?
It suddenly started to appear while no changes occurred on my app.

Comment: Just to update - my issue caused due to 3-rd party running on the machine, cortex xdr by Palo alto. When we disabled it, the issue was not reproduced.

Comment: @amiorlin Thanks for that update. I can see that the same 3rd party is running on my machine as well!

Answer (score 0):

In my company's laptop, because of cortex IDR update it started appearing. Solution would be add -XVerify:none in your VM argument in IDE.
[image]